# SQL select where not exists

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have 4 table

```
branch          target         target_dept   dept
--------        ---------      -----------   --------
branch_id       target_id      target_id     dept_id
branch_name     branch_id      dept_id       dept_name
```

i want to select all branch with dept that has relation
here my query

```
select b.branch_id, b.branch_name,dept.dept_name
from branch b
left join target ptar on ptar.branch_id=b.branch_id
left join target_dept pdept on pdept.target_id=ptar.target_id
left join dept dept on pdept.dept_id=dept.dept_id
```

I get what i want to get with that query. Lets say the output like this (there are 5 data on dept)

```
B001 | KUALA LUMPUR | DEPT1
B001 | KUALA LUMPUR | DEPT2
B002 | BALI         | DEPT3
B002 | BALI         | DEPT4
B002 | BALI         | DEPT5
B003 | MANILLA      |
```

And i want to get the branch with dept that hadnt any relation yet, therefore i used not exists query like this

```
select b.branch_id, b.branch_name,dept.dept_name
from branch b
left join target ptar on ptar.branch_id=b.branch_id
left join target_dept pdept on pdept.target_id=ptar.target_id
left join dept dept on not exists(select null where pdept.dept_id=dept.dept_id)
```

the output i want to get is like this

```
B001 | KUALA LUMPUR | DEPT3
B001 | KUALA LUMPUR | DEPT4
B001 | KUALA LUMPUR | DEPT5
B002 | BALI         | DEPT1
B002 | BALI         | DEPT2
B003 | MANILLA      | DEPT1
B003 | MANILLA      | DEPT2
B003 | MANILLA      | DEPT3
B003 | MANILLA      | DEPT4
B003 | MANILLA      | DEPT5
```

But the output that i really get is not what i exactly want

Comment: Add sample table data and its expected result. (As well formatted text.)

Comment: Please tag your dbms

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your aim, try this:

This query selects all branches not linked with departments

**The strategy:**

I apply a cartesian product between branchs and departments, so I've discarded all departements linked to your branch, so remain only the branches without link to departments.

```
SELECT b.branch_id, b.branch_name,dept.dept_name
FROM branch b
CROSS JOIN dept d
WHERE NOT EXISTS(
    SELECT 'LINKED'
    FROM target T
    JOIN target_dept TD
        ON T.target_id = TD.target_id
    JOIN dept D2
        ON D2.dept_id = TD.dept_id
    WHERE D2.dept_id = d.dept_id
    AND b.branch_id = t.branch_id
)
```

Comment: Great answer thank you, would you explain the detail?

Comment: why i failed at this ->select b.branch_id, b.branch_name, string_agg(DISTINCT dept.dept_name,',') as departmens..........where not exists(................) group by b.branch_id, b.branch_name

Comment: I suppose string_agg params must be a subquery. If you want write in one row all deps the query deeply change